# Web designer's link back to own website (rel="designer" / rel="nofollow")

Tags: seo, links, nofollow, rel

I read somewhere that web designers' habit of placing a default "follow" link in the footer of their client websites is bad for SEO.

Is this true?

If so, should we use `rel="nofollow"` instead.

I have seen `rel="designer"` in some free WordPress themes.

Comment: Unless your niche is about web designing which I doubt then in today's climate you should not be linking back to non-relevant sites. If your site is about Cars then only link out to sites about cars since this will help your authority - it will also help your website designer since he should be seeking links from sites within his/her niche too. Days of any old links are over relevancy is everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I tend to do is write a conditional (or do do it by hand if it's a static HTML site) so that on the home page it says:

`<a href="http://mysite.com">My site</a>`

but on all other pages it says:

`<a href="http://mysite.com" rel="nofollow">My site</a>`

That way you get the benefit of the link juice from the home page (which is usually the strongest page) which isn't then eroded by having a site-wide link.

Alternatively you could make the link live on the home page only, and on all other pages have it writen in static text: `<p>Site by me</p>` without a link.

As for the `rel="designer"`, I haven't come across that before.

Comment: +1 Good answer. I think `rel="designer"`originates back to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XHTML_Friends_Network) network, which seems dormant now. It's really of no benefit.

Answer (score 2):

It is bad in context of Goolge's fighting with spam through "Penguin". This "Penguin" punishs for "site-wide" links.

My piece of advice for you is to use `rel="nofollow"`. It will prevent you from any filter actions but leave your link available for users.